# bitbake how to differentiate a single package for multiple machines

Tags: bitbake

I'm using yocto project's 1.1.1 version. Bitbake: BitBake Build Tool Core version 1.13.3, bitbake version 1.13.3.

I have my own layer: meta-mine. I have three machines defined in meta-mine/conf/machine/ Let's call them ab.conf and cd.conf and ef.conf

Everything's working fine, but I would like to create a recipe which is a bit too complicated for my little knowledge of bitbake.

I've created different initscripts for ab end cd machine, also I need both of them for ef. Unfortunately I don't know how to accomplish that.

**Idea 1**
What I was thinking of:
.
.
.
    PACKAGES = "${PN} ${PN}-ab ${PN}-cd"
    COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_${PN}-ab = "ab ef"
    COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_${PN}-karo = "cd ef"
    FILES_${PN}-ab = "${sysconfdir}/init.d/absript"
    FILES_${PN}-cd = "${sysconfdir}/init.d/cdsript"

```
inherit update-rc.d

INITSCRIPT_PACKAGES = "${PN} ${PN}-ab ${PN}-cd"

INITSCRIPT_NAME_${PN}-ab = "abscript"
INITSCRIPT_PARAMS_${PN}-ab = "start 93 S ."

INITSCRIPT_NAME_${PN}-cd = "cdscript"
INITSCRIPT_PARAMS_${PN}-cd = "start 11 S ."
```

I haven't tried that, but even if it works.. I would like to be served completely, so when I add mycomplicatepackage to my IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL, I want it to install the right initscripts for the current machine. (in build/conf/local.conf)

Sorry for my bad english, I hope I could explain what exaclty I'm wishing for.

**Idea 2:**
I've seen somewhere this:

```
TARGET_ab = "xy"
TARGET_cd = "yz"  
.  
.  
INITSCRIPT_NAME_xy = "abscript"
INITSCRIPT_PARAMS_xy = "S 93 ."

INITSCRIPT_NAME_yz = "cdscipt"
INITSCRIPT_PARAMS_yz = "start 11 S ."
```

I don't know how TARGET variable works, and I couldn't find any related documentation about it. (maybe I didn't try hard enough...) However It doesn't show how to install both scripts for ef machine.

I really appretiate any suggestions or solutions. Ask me if you need more details to find out what I want :)

Comment: Seems it remainds unsolved. I've found another solution what fits my situation, but still... would be nice to get a "nice" solution for this issue.